# Proper use of sscanf to parse string c++

Tags: c++, scanf

Text in buffer:

```
Source$1
Destination$5
```

Code:

```
char buffer[50];
int start = 0;
int dest = 0;
FILE * infile = fopen(argv[1], "r")

fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), infile);
sscanf(buffer, "Source$%d", &start); 
printf("start: %d \n", start);
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), infile);
sscanf(buffer, "Destination$%d", &dest);
printf("destination: %d \n", dest);
```

Output:

```
start: 0
destination: 5
```

Destination is getting the right number, start isn't.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Show a complete example. We're having to guess what type `source` and `dest` are meant to be, and what `buffer` is.

Comment: The proper use in C++ is to remove it from your code and use the type-safe alternatives provided by the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: Edited to be more complete,  I wasn't aware to not use sscanf?

Comment: @tdwig `sscanf`comes from C rather than C++. It's rightly frowned on by many due to the lack of parameter type checking. But the 'good' C++ alternatives are often awkward to use and inflexible, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see anything wrong in your posted code. It will be better for you to add code to perform error checks. Then you can see where the problem is.

```
if ( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), infile) )
{
   printf("%s", buffer);
   if ( sscanf(buffer, "Source$%d", &start) == 1 )
   {
      printf("start: %d \n", start);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Unable to read source from buffer\n");
   }
}
else
{
   printf("Unable to read the text for source\n");
}


if ( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), infile) )
{
   printf("%s", buffer);
   if ( sscanf(buffer, "Destination$%d", &dest) == 1 )
   {
      printf("destination: %d \n", dest);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Unable to read destination from buffer\n");
   }
}
else
{
   printf("Unable to read the text for destination\n");
}
```